# How does a MOSFET work? (FQP30N06L)

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I read everywhere that there needs to be a certain voltage at the gate so that current can flow between drain and source.

But in my MOSFET (FQP30N06L) drain and source are connected and current always flows between them. 
So I can drive a motor without using the gate at all. 
But how do I actually switch? How do I turn the motor off?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fta8o1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm referring to gate as 1 (the pin on the left). 
Drain is pin 2 (the one in the middle). 
And source is pin 3. (the one on the right).

Comment: Drain and source positions as described by your words do not tally with your diagram. Plus you mention pin numbers as references but these are not in the picture. Fix your contradictions please. How do you know there isn't voltage at the gate without measuring it? An open circuit does not imply zero voltage but the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that I needed a pulldown resistor at the gate. 
Well, back then I did not know what a pulldown resistor is, 
so that answer would not have helped me much. 
But the answer is to place a resistor with at least 1k ohms between the gate (first pin of the FQP30n06I) and ground. 
Then you can pull the pin high by closing the switch. 
Without pulldown resistor the MOSFET stays closed and it takes a very long time 
until it the resistance rises again.

Answer (score 1):

If your drain and source are always connected, then either

- your FET is broken
- you've left the high impedance gate unconnected, and it's got some charge on it from somewhere, and is sitting at a Vgs high enough to make the FET conduct

Connect the gate to the source, and remeasure. If the drain and source are still connected, replace the FET.

Try this circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGQ18G.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The resistor values aren't too important, other than that R1 should be much larger than R2, to allow Vgs to get to most of 9 V when the switch is closed. When the switch is open, R1 pulls Vgs down to 0 V.

This common source configuration is preferred to the common drain you've shown when using N channel FETs, as the Vgs is easier to provide.

Comment: I connected 1 and 3 of the MOSFET and indeed the connection between 2 and 3 was gone. <br> But current did still flow between 2 and 3. Then I took some new MOSFETs and it was the same on every MOSFET, current flows between 2 and 3.

Comment: Please provide the schematic of the circuit you have set up. It can be something very simple that we are overlooking.

Comment: @theerrormagnet 'the connection was gone, but current still flowed' is contradictory.

Comment: I think the problem might be that I did not connect the gate to the minus pole of the battery. I think I need a potentiometer that connects to the gate. If there is a resistance no current flows from source to drain, and if there is no resistance current flows from source to drain. But I'm still trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @theerrormagnet I've updated my answer with a test circuit.

Comment: @theerrormagnet Be aware that there will always be a current path from source to drain through the FET's parasitic body diode. Drain-to-source current can be blocked, but source-to-drain can't (at least not with a regular old three-pin MOSFET).